# I m using Angular Marial 16. While implementing mat-select inside mat-card , mat-option dropdown box is going down of page

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material 16, using mat-select inide of mat-card. but mat-option are coming down of card layout
[Dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG8II.png)

```
`<mat-card style="height: 50%; width: 40%;align-items: center;">
 <mat-card-content>
                <div >
                    <mat-form-field >
                        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
                        <mat-select>
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]=[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjiT.png)"food.value">
                            {{food.viewValue}}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>`your text`
          </mat-card>

in .ts
foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
  ];`
```

Tried to implement mat-select dropdown. But mat-options are going outside of mat-card.It should be come inside and along with the mat-select input field.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved when I add @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; in style.css file